# C Prog - While loop

Tags: c

Hi once again I have found myself stuck with coding. I have found the correct code but I do not understand why my initial coding does not work. Could anyone explain briefly the problem?

My initial code and the runnable code is posted below.

INITIAL CODE (does not work as expected)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main(void)
{
   int counter;
   int num1, num2, smallest;

   counter = 1;

   printf("Enter first number:");
   scanf("%d", &num1);
   smallest = num1;

   while (counter <= 10) // User input phase
   {
      printf("Enter next numer:");
      scanf("%d", &num2);

      if (num1 < num2)
      {
         smallest = num1;
      }
      if (num2 < num1)
      {
         smallest = num2;
      }

      counter++;
   }

   printf("Smallest is %d", smallest);

   getch();
}
```

RUNNABLE CODE

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main(void)

{
    int counter;
    int num1, smallest;

    counter = 1;


    printf("Enter first number:");
    scanf("%d", &num1);
    smallest = num1;

    while (counter <= 10) // User input phase
    {
        printf("Enter next numer:");
        scanf("%d", &num1);

        if (num1 < smallest)
        {
            smallest = num1;
        }
        if (smallest < num1)
        {
            smallest = smallest;
        }

            counter++;
    }

    printf("Smallest is %d", smallest);

    getch();
}
```

Comment: Compile with all warnings & debug info (e.g. `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` if using [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)....) and **use the debugger** (e.g. `gdb`)

Answer (score 1):

In your first attempt you save the value of smallest each loop, but you get rid of it because of the next loop will check always `num1` and new entered number in `num2`.

In the second code, the working one, the loop is keeping track of the last smallest found.

A little thing, the code chunk

```
    if (num1 < smallest)
    {
        smallest = num1;
    }
    if (smallest < num1)
    {
        smallest = smallest;
    }
```

the second `if` does not make sense, you can write

```
    if (num1 < smallest)
    {
        smallest = num1;
    }
    else
    {
        smallest = smallest;
    }
```

or better

```
    if (num1 < smallest)
    {
        smallest = num1;
    }
```

Comment: OK, I didn't see your edit. We can remove these comments now.

Comment: Oh! Thank you for pointing that out! I really gotta start thinking C to do coding.